# Prove $f(x,y,z)=x^2-2y^2+3z^2$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z)=x^2-2y^2+3z^2$. Prove $f$ is differentiable using the following definition and basic algebra.

The function **f** is differentiable at **a** if there exists a linear transformation $\textbf{f'}(\textbf{a}): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and a function **r**:$E \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that for all **x** $\in E$
$$\textbf{f}(\textbf{x})=\textbf{f'}(\textbf{a})(\textbf{x}-\textbf{a})+\textbf{f}(\textbf{a})+\textbf{r}(\textbf{x}) \text{ and } \lim_{\textbf{x} \to \textbf{a}} \frac{||\textbf{r}(\textbf{x})||}{||\textbf{x}-\textbf{a}||} =0$$.

So confused.

Comment: Is it really $3x^2$? Or $3z^2$?

Comment: yes thank u, it is $3z^2$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we're looking for a linear transformation $Df(\mathbf a)\colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ which is a close approximation to $f$ near some point $\mathbf a \in \mathbb R^3$ (this corresponds to the condition that the limit vanishes).

As a well-informed guess, lets say
$$Df(\mathbf a) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a_1) & \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}(a_2) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a_3)
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This definition of $Df$ will work in general for any differentiable function. Can you fill in why it satisfies the necessary conditions?

Edit: It may be valuable to think of the graph of $f$ as defining some surface in $\mathbb R^4$. From this point of view, the differentiability of $f$ at $\mathbf a$ is equivalent to the graph of $f$ having a well defined tangent plane at $\mathbf a$. The map $Df$ is a natural guess to define this tangent plane since by definition it is tangent in the $x,y,$ and $z$ directions individually.